# web/unix interface: what to use?

Tags: unix

I wish to make a simple web page, which will strongly interact with unix commands behind.  And I'm sure there exist some wonderful technology out there which would be suited to do just that and get you running in a couple of hours. I just don't know which one. Now, please let me explain what I intend to do.

Basically, it is very simple:
The page shows a list of tasks which are either sussess / failure / running states. These tasks and states are simply mirroring what's in a given directory and some unix commands to determine the state.

Then, there should be a small button to "add a task". People are invited to put in login/password (or register first if needed), then are allowed to enter some configuration for the new task. Basically some text and options.

This "task" then belongs to the user. Which should be able to stop/restart or even delete it. As usual, any of these operations are directly linked to executing a set of unix commands.

...that's it. What I'm looking is the easiest, most transparent/elegant way to put this in place. What do you advise me to use?

Regards,

Arnaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...in the meantime, I more or less solved it with:
http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html

It's very lightweight and suited my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've ever looked at the Webmin project -- http://webmin.com/. It has several excellant options for creating your own plugins to their web based framework. It's specifically targeted at Admins looking to control Unix boxen.